# Missing '#include <grp.h>'; declaration of 'getgrgid' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.grp' before it is required

Tags: c++, c, xcode, libarchive

I use "libarchive" for my xcode project:

```
static const char *
lookup_gname_helper(struct name_cache *cache, id_t id)
{
struct group    *result;
(void)cache; /* UNUSED */

result = getgrgid((gid_t)id);

if (result == NULL)
return (NULL);

return strdup(result->gr_name);
}
```

And I'm getting bellow errors:

> Conflicting types for 'getgrgid'
>
> Implicit declaration of function 'getgrgid' is invalid in C99
>
> Missing '#include '; declaration of 'getgrgid' must be imported
>   from module 'Darwin.POSIX.grp' before it is required
>
> Missing '#include '; definition of 'group' must be imported
>   from module 'Darwin.POSIX.grp' before it is required

How can I fix this errors?

Source: https://github.com/LuaDist/libarchive/blob/master/libarchive/archive_read_disk_set_standard_lookup.c

Comment: You need to run the configure script, so that `HAVE_GRP_H` actually gets defined.  You cannot just dump all of the C files into an Xcode project.

Comment: Try adding the line `#include <grp.h>` at the top.